# Getting Map size on memory(RAM)

Tags: java, memory, dictionary

I am using a HashMap to cache some important data when my application starts.
This cache sometime grows and then reduced. I want to know how much memory it is taking on RAM.
Is it possible to get memory taken by a map in KB? Is there any API?

Comment: You should use an existing java heap profiler to study your memory consumption. For example [this one](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Comment: Ya I am doing that. I just wanted to monitor that how much memory it is taking in storing this Map. I want to display it on jsp somehow.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot get the size of a map by a single method call. You could attempt to get the # of entries in the map and if your entries are something you can estimate the size of you can go on doing that. Otherwise you can attempt to profile your code with a tool like JVisualVM and get a figure on how much memory is been eaten by Maps

Comment: @NIVESHSENGAR please let us know if AValchev's solution works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i'm using this method to estimate the MAP size:

```
public static void size(Map map) {
    try{
        System.out.println("Index Size: " + map.size());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(map);
        oos.close();
        System.out.println("Data Size: " + baos.size());
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if its good for big size map data, since it seems like those methods are using a buffer which also takes space in RAM

Comment: I'll use that for estimation purpose.

Answer (score 7):

There is a good tool for this purpose: [ClassMexer](http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/)

You can estimate the memory of the HashMap, including referenced objects by:

long noBytes = MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(myCacheMap);

Answer (score 4):

You realize, of course, that your `Map` holds references to objects that live out on the heap, not the objects themselves.  So it's meaningless to ask how much memory the `Map` is consuming without chasing down the entire reference tree to add up the bytes for the keys and the values.

The object doesn't do it; there's no way to accomplish it.

Like the wise comment above said, get Visual VM with all the plugins and profile your app.

Answer (score 3):

It's virtually impossible to compute the real size of an object without instrumentation.

Sometimes you can compute it given the size of pointers, primitive types, the overhead of objects, etc. but doing it for something as complex as a HashMap with content (the real size  size is dependent of its history and hash factor and the hascode of all its elements modulo the hash factor) is near impossible.

The only real solution is to use a heap analyzer, such as [Eclipse Mat](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends very much on your JVM vendor and version. You can have a look at [this presentation](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pldi09tutorials/memory-efficient-java-tutorial.pdf) for a rough estimation.